# Download Excel file from Server C#

Tags: c#, download, asp.net-core-mvc

I am generating an Excel file in a Hangfire background job in my ASP.NET Core MVC site.

I am running into some issues with getting an excel file to download correctly from my website. When I try to download the file when it is running on localhost, it works completely fine. After the code is published and I try to use the feature on the live version, I can't get the file to download.

```
string previewName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\" + content + " - " + Guid.NewGuid() + ".xlsx";
File.Copy(sourceFileName, previewName);
```

I originally had written this, thinking I would be able to download the file to the client's My Documents folder. I have learned that this is not the case since Environment.GetFolderpath gets the folder path for the servers computer and not the clients. Since the file is hosted on the server, how can I download that file to the client's computer?

Comment: It is Core MVC but I am creating the excel file asynchronously using Hangfire jobs. Therefore, I cannot write to an Http Response.

Comment: You're correct, in Hangfire you wouldn't have a response available to write that at the same time. That's okay. You just have to change the process up a bit. So you generate this file - you're going to save it somewhere on the server side (or perhaps in the database, or maybe in the cloud like AWS S3 or Azure Blob Storage). At that point you need a page within your app for the user to come hit later to download the file - like a downloads page perhaps. And you might also implement a notification system that can notify a user their file is ready to download....

Comment: ..They click a link, that hits an action method, and then your action method grabs the file from wherever it's stored and writes the file to the response. A SignalR notification may be useful for that. Another option is to have the user install some sort of app on their machine that polls waiting for the file to be ready (or gets a push notification) and moves the file to the right place on the user's behalf.

Comment: please provide more information as there are to many assumptions to provide a robust answer.

Comment: @mason Okay thank you, I never thought about creating a new page they can check when the file is ready with a download button. I will try to implement this.

Comment: No problem - we use the same pattern in our own application when generating big reports asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a WebClient to download the file from the site.

```
using System.Net;

string URL = "https://server.com/files/file.txt";
var FilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\" + content + " - " + Guid.NewGuid() + ".xlsx");

WebClient Client = new WebClient();
Client.DownloadFile(URL, FilePath);
```

Comment: This assumes the C# is running on the client, which doesn't seem to be the case from the question.

Comment: @mason Correct. I don't think the guy read the post because I explained that the Enviroment.GetFolderPath() method is returning the servers computer and not the clients.

Comment: If you're running a server try using a ftp library and download it using it.

Comment: Why would someone run an FTP server just to download a file from a website? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: keyword was "server". I literally don't know if OP is talking about a website OR a server.

Comment: @rodrigo Sorry, for clarification, the excel file is created through Hangfire when a button is pressed on the website. The issue is that the file is sent to a server once it is created and when I was trying to use Enviroment.GetFolderPath(), it would return the servers computer not the current clients. I am implementing a new process that mason advised.

Answer (score 1):

if it is a controller your talking about than instead of copying you can download directly by returning the file in the Controller

```
return File(yourFilePath);
```

or you can read the file as bytes and then return it

```
bytes[] bytesFile = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
return File(bytesFile);
```